# Summing data based on Column in R

Tags: r, sum, cluster-analysis

I have a data set that looks like this (actual data is 10K by 5K so I really need a shortcut):

| Cluster | Item1 | Item2 | Item 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 2 |

I want to add the columns of each data set by cluster so it will look I this:

| Cluster | Item1 | Item2 | Item 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 6 | 3 |
| 2 | 7 | 4 | 4 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 |

I want to sum them by a certain column.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `aggregate` (`dat` is the name of your data frame):

```
aggregate(dat[-1], dat["Cluster"], sum)

#   Cluster Item1 Item2 Item3
# 1       1     5     6     3
# 2       2     7     4     4
# 3       3     1     2     3
```

---

With `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[ , lapply(.SD, sum), by = Cluster]
#    Cluster Item1 Item2 Item3
# 1:       1     5     6     3
# 2:       2     7     4     4
# 3:       3     1     2     3
```

---

With `dplyr`:

```
dat %>%
  group_by(Cluster) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(sum))
#   Cluster Item1 Item2 Item3
# 1       1     5     6     3
# 2       2     7     4     4
# 3       3     1     2     3
```

Comment: thanks for your answer I also used this good and it worked perfectly:
 aggregate(. ~ Cluster, data=dat, FUN=sum)

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your answer, I also used this good and it worked perfectly:

```
 aggregate(. ~ Cluster, data=dat, FUN=sum)



#   Cluster Item1 Item2 Item3
# 1       1     5     6     3
# 2       2     7     4     4
# 3       3     1     2     3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
> sapply(ddf[-1], function(x) tapply(x,ddf$Cluster,sum))
  Item1 Item2 Item3
1     5     6     3
2     7     4     4
3     1     2     3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sum all varibales except that of grouping, use `across` in dplyr

```
df <- read.table(text = "Cluster    Item1   Item2   Item3
1   1   2   2
1   3   1   1
1   1   3   0
2   3   2   0
2   0   0   2
2   4   2   2
3   0   1   1
3   1   1   2", header = T)

df %>% group_by(Cluster) %>% summarise(across(everything(), ~sum(.)))

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  Cluster Item1 Item2 Item3
    <int> <int> <int> <int>
1       1     5     6     3
2       2     7     4     4
3       3     1     2     3
```